# axios call not getting mocked

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, sinon

My React component uses Axios to make a call to an API. In my unit test, I'm trying to mock the Axios by using Sandbox stub from Sinon like this:

```
sandbox1 = sandbox.create();
            const resolved = new Promise((r) => r([{ id: 1, name: 'PetA' }, { id: 2, name:'PetB' }]));
            sandbox1.stub(axios, 'get').returns(resolved);
```

I want to test the below piece of code

```
this.setState(
            ({ testing }) => ({
                testing: {
                    ...testing,
                    [testKey]: {
                        isExecuting: true,
                        response: null
                    }
                }
            }),
            () => {
                axios(req)
                    .then(r => {
                        this.setState(state => {
                            const cancelled =
                                state.testing &&
                                state.testing[testKey] &&
                                state.testing[testKey]['cancelled'];
                            return !cancelled
                                ? {
                                    test: {
                                        ...state.test,
                                        [testKey]: {
                                            isExecuting: false,
                                            cancelled: false,
                                            response: r
                                        }
                                    }
                                  }
                                : undefined;
                        });
                    })


this is followed by catch block 
and closed paranthesis of setState
```

The problem is when I run the test with stubbed axios as shown in the beginning, I always get the following as the resulting state at the end

```
{ testing: { 'get_/pets': { isExecuting: true, response: null } } }
```

This means that the axios is not resolving the promise, despite the instructions given while stubbing it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you should use the stubed function so instead of calling `axios(req)` you should call `axios.get(req)` since `axios` as a function is not getting stubed

Comment: Thanks for your input..actually axios(req) is in the code that needs to be tested, not in the test...
In the test, I have this line:
sandbox1.stub(axios, 'get').returns(resolved);